# Trouble with Divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

I have a load of divs, and they're either aligned and cleared left or right. But I have some odd behavior here:

[image]

Basically, on the top half, two divs meet at their top and bottom, but floated different directions, so it's as if the left top grey box will never be side-by-side or above the right top grey box, only exactly below it.

Same situation but reversed on the bottom.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS so we can see what is going on please?

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the combined width of the two floated elements per line are bigger than the width of their container (*you need to factor in the widths + paddings + margins + borders..*)?

This example works http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mLa7K/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box left short">top left</div>
    <div class="box right short">top right</div>
    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="box left long">bottom left</div>
    <div class="box right long">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

with

```
#container{
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.box{
    width:140px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
    margin:30px 0;
}
.short{height:30px}
.long{height:130px;}
```